# Hacer que textbox solo acepte ciertos caracteres en wpf

Tags: wpf

Quiero hacer que mi textbox solo acepte ciertos caracteres (en mi caso solo números).

Este es el código que tengo:

```
private void textBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = !"D0D1D2D3D4D5D6D7D8D9.\b".Contains(e.Key.ToString());
    }
```

El problema del código es que la letra "*D*" sigue estando disponible, y si elimino las "*Ds*" del código, se bloquea cualquier tipo de caracter(números, letras , simbolos, etc).

Answer (score 0):

Esto es muy sencillo, puedes lograrlo de esta forma (entre varias más) y consta de 2 partes:

**Primero**: Crea esta clase (renómbrala si quieres):

**AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;

namespace MyApp.Behaviors
{
    public class AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior : Behavior<TextBox>
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty RegularExpressionProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("RegularExpression", typeof(string), typeof(AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(".*"));
        public string RegularExpression
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)base.GetValue(RegularExpressionProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(RegularExpressionProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxLength", typeof(int), typeof(AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(int.MinValue));
        public int MaxLength
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)base.GetValue(MaxLengthProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                base.SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value);
            }
        }

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput += OnPreviewTextInput;
            DataObject.AddPastingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPaste);
        }

        private void OnPaste(object sender, DataObjectPastingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.DataObject.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text))
            {
                string text = Convert.ToString(e.DataObject.GetData(DataFormats.Text));

                if (!IsValid(text, true))
                {
                    e.CancelCommand();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.CancelCommand();
            }
        }

        void OnPreviewTextInput(object sender, System.Windows.Input.TextCompositionEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = !IsValid(e.Text, false);
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            base.OnDetaching();
            AssociatedObject.PreviewTextInput -= OnPreviewTextInput;
            DataObject.RemovePastingHandler(AssociatedObject, OnPaste);
        }

        private bool IsValid(string newText, bool paste)
        {
            return !ExceedsMaxLength(newText, paste) && Regex.IsMatch(newText, RegularExpression);
        }

        private bool ExceedsMaxLength(string newText, bool paste)
        {
            if (MaxLength == 0) return false;

            return LengthOfModifiedText(newText, paste) > MaxLength;
        }

        private int LengthOfModifiedText(string newText, bool paste)
        {
            var countOfSelectedChars = this.AssociatedObject.SelectedText.Length;
            var caretIndex = this.AssociatedObject.CaretIndex;
            string text = this.AssociatedObject.Text;

            if (countOfSelectedChars > 0 || paste)
            {
                text = text.Remove(caretIndex, countOfSelectedChars);
                return text.Length + newText.Length;
            }
            else
            {
                var insert = Keyboard.IsKeyToggled(Key.Insert);

                return insert && caretIndex < text.Length ? text.Length : text.Length + newText.Length;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Segundo**: Utilízala como Property de tu TextBox

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.MyDialog"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
xmlns:behaviors="clr-namespace:MyApp.Behaviors"
Title="MyApp">
    <Grid>      
        <TextBox Text="" MaxLength="10" >
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <behaviors:AllowableCharactersTextBoxBehavior RegularExpression="^[0-9.\-]+$" MaxLength="10" />
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>      
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Y listo, puedes tener TextBox con cualquier restricción únicamente cambiando la Expresión Regular que lo controla.

Un saludo.